# How to remove page title (h1) from home page, cms_index_index.xml not working

Tags: magento2, layout, page-title

I´m trying to remove the home page main title on my custom theme (wich is running on top of luma theme).

I´ve tried to add the usual tag to remove, as follows (and as it was already answered here), full content of my current `cms_index_index.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I´ve already tried other aproaches such as

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="false"/>
```

And

```
<referenceBlock name="cms_page" display="false"/>
```

With no success either. Cache is being cleaned and files deployed.
The cms_index_index.xml file i´m working in is located on folder

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout
```

What other options do i have? Why isn´t this aproach working?

Comment: Your code is definitely ok (the first code you tried) I've just tested it and it works fine on my side. I reckon your XML is not being picked up for some reason. Did you check the logs ?

Answer (score 36):

have you tried in `cms_index_index.xml` something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Yup, this is the way to go. If you want to remove it on a category page, for example you put this in `catalog_category_view.xml` file. And you can omit the `layout` attribute inside the `<page>` element.

Answer (score 11):

For all other Pages create `cms_page_view.xml` instead cms_index_index.xml

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view.xml
```

And add same code you have used for cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 5):

- Login to Admin
- Goto Content->Element: pages->
- Edit HomePage
- Select Content
- Remove Contet Heading and Save.

Comment: I think this is the first thing to try. Because I was looking exactly for the same thing and I almost tried the code part. But with this, it was fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

- Check cms home page. `content-> pages-> home page`
- than open that page and check that content heading is blank or not.
- If it is not than remove heading. Now its removed form your front page

Answer (score 0):

If your certain your **XML is valid** but **not picked up by Magent**o, make sure that you check the table "theme" inside your Magento database.

The column "type" should have the value 0 (zero), for your theme.

If it is set to 1 (virtual) it will not pickup the overwrites that you defined inside your `app/design` custom theme folder.

Once you set it to 0, make sure that you clear all the cache, `pub/static/frontend`, `var/view_preprocessed` and re-check if your changes are now working.

Answer (score 0):

Open homepage from Admin
Goto >> **Design** >> **Layout Update XML** add line

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: mag2.2.2 give `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 6`

Answer (score 0):

i) Go to Admin=>content=>element=>pages
ii) select page=>edit=>changes:- page title[image]